# Languages changing menu for changing different language

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

How we can change the languages as per selection done from the language menu.

Comment: You mean how to implement a menu so that user could switch the language? What is wrong with preselected language (the one that user already set in his/her phone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **res** folder, you should have a folder called **values**. Inside that folder, place a **strings.xml** file.

The **strings.xml** files should contain something like this

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App Name</string>
    <string name="someText">someText in default language</string>
    <string name="nonTranslatedText">someText only in default language</string>
</resources>
```

If you want to support other languages, just create additional **values** folders inside res, also containing a string.xml file, containing the translations.

So if you want to support Dutch for example, create a strings.xml in a **values-nl** folder, containing this :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App Name in Dutch</string>
    <string name="someText">someText in Dutch</string>
</resources>
```

The translations will be automatically picked up by Android when the user switches languages. If no translations can be found for the given language (ex: the nonTranslatedText string), it will default to the ones found in **res/values/strings.xml**.

You can refer to these strings in layouts like this :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/someId" style="@style/someStyle" android:text="@string/someText"/>
```

Or in java objects like this :

```
context.getString(R.string.someText);
```

Answer (score 3):

public static Typeface hindiTypeface;

```
public static Typeface getTypeface(Context mContext) {

    int languageOptionValue = 0;
    if (WelcomeActivity.userSettings != null) {
        languageOptionValue = WelcomeActivity.userSettings.getInt(
                "language", 0);
    }

    if (languageOptionValue == 1) {
        if (hindiTypeface == null)
            hindiTypeface = initHindiFont(mContext);
        return hindiTypeface;
    } else {
        return Typeface.DEFAULT;
    }
}

public static Typeface initHindiFont(Context mContext) {

    AssetManager assetManagerHindi = mContext.getAssets();
    try {
        assetManagerHindi.open("droid_hindi.ttf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManagerHindi, "droid_hindi.ttf");

}
```

These is for playing with hindi text in api level 4.